# Add new rows to a MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, multi-index

Given this MultiIndex Dataframe:

```
arrays = [np.array(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']),
         np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6), index=arrays, columns=['col1'])
```

I would like to add a new row (inner index) to every row in the outer index.

```
df.loc[(slice(None),'three'),:] = {'A':3, 'B':4, 'C':5}
```

However this gives me an error:
    KeyError: 'three'

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: All values in the row are **not** the same.

Answer (score 7):

#### [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) + `reindex`

```
a, b = df.index.levels

res = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a, [*b, 'three']]))
res[res.index.get_level_values(1) == 'three'] = 3
```

```
             col1
A one   -1.011201
  two    0.376914
  three  3.000000
B one    0.465666
  two   -0.634804
  three  3.000000
C one   -0.348338
  two    1.295683
  three  3.000000
```

---

An update to this answer to account for your desire to add specific values.  Replace the last line with this code snippet:

```
d = {'A':3, 'B':4, 'C':5}
s = res.index.get_level_values(0).map(d)
res.col1.where(res.col1.notnull(), s.values)
```

```
A  one     -2.542087
   two      0.966193
   three    3.000000
B  one     -0.126671
   two      0.864258
   three    4.000000
C  one      0.063544
   two     -0.401936
   three    5.000000
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I edited the question for clarity. This does not address the problem fully because it puts the same value (3) in all the rows.

Comment: @apkul updated my answer to demonstrate how to map custom values

Comment: Alternatively for the mapping of values to specific values of the first index level: 
m = res.index.get_level_values(1) == 'three'
res.loc[m,'col1'] = res.loc[m].index.get_level_values(0).map({'A':3, 'B':4, 'C':5})

Answer (score 5):

Possibly verbose, but you can construct a new dataframe, concatenate, then sort by index:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, 'three') for i in df.index.levels[0]])
df_new = pd.DataFrame(3, index=idx, columns=df.columns)

df = pd.concat([df, df_new]).sort_index()

print(df)

             col1
A one   -0.810362
  three  3.000000
  two    0.014020
B one    0.700392
  three  3.000000
  two    0.189968
C one   -1.214194
  three  3.000000
  two    1.199316
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `concat`

```
s=pd.Series({'A':3, 'B':4, 'C':5}).to_frame('col1').assign(index='three')
pd.concat([df,s.set_index('index',append=True)]).sort_index(level=0)
Out[205]: 
             col1
A one    0.529647
  three  3.000000
  two   -1.763707
B one   -0.673773
  three  4.000000
  two   -0.706385
C one    1.105963
  three  5.000000
  two    1.291009
```